# Change UIView location with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, cgrectmake

I'm trying to change the location of a `UIView` with `NSLayoutConstraint`, but it seems my constraint is not having an effect.

Here is my code:

```
var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50))
self.view.addSubview(view)
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
self.view.addConstraint(topConstraint)
```

The example seems trivial, but I need these constraints to work for something I'm doing later on. Why doesn't this work and how should I be thinking about this differently?

Thanks!

Comment: You should not set any frames when you use layout constraints. Also, you need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false for code created views. You will also need height and width constraints for your view, or its size will be zero. You also need a horizontal constraint.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you for your reply.  I'm trying to set the height of the view to be sufficiently large to contain the titleLabel of a UIButton subview.  How can I do this without setting the frame of the superview?  Seems as though I can't do this using constraints alone.

Comment: Yes you can, you need to set height and width constraints for view. Those constraints should be added to view, not to self.view.

Comment: @rdelmar How can a set a height relative to an object that does not exist on the view? (eg. `NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: ???, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)`)

Comment: Do you want it to be relative to something, or just a fixed number? If you want it to be relative to the button, then you don't set the height at all. You set spacing constraints between the button, and all four sides of view. The button will have an intrinsic size based on it's title, and that will force its superview to be that size plus whatever padding you give it.

Comment: @rdelmar "The button will have an intrinsic size based on it's title[...]" The issue I'm having is that the button is not resizing based on its title.  I set the `lineBreakMode` to `.ByWordWrapping` and while it does wrap properly, it does not increase the height of the button and the text overflows the frame.

Comment: Well, that's a different problem from what you've posted here. If that's the problem you're having, then ask another question with the details of how your button is set up.